# How to cut xml files and move them to a different location based on nodes via powershell , batchfile

Tags: xml, powershell, pst

I require to cut or move XML files based on the nodes,
etc I want to search through the file pick up EG  FX 
and move the files containing tfx to a different location

I've tried the following with no success

```
$dir = 'C:\temp\source'
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.xml | Foreach-Object {
  $Instrument = Select-Xml -Xpath '/deal' -Path $_.FullName  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  If($Instrument.node.innertext -eq "FX_Cross"){
    Move-Item "C:\temp\source\*.xml" "C:\temp\destination\FX" -Force
  } Else{
    Move-Item "C:\temp\source\*.xml" "C:\temp\destination\" -Force
  }
}
```

no result above does not run

Comment: You should consider using your current object in your `Move-Item` commands: `Move-Item $_ "C:\temp\destination\FX" -Force` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the wasy there (I think, I need a sample of your XML file to be really sure), I think you're getting hung up here

```
Move-Item "C:\temp\source\*.xml" "C:\temp\destination\FX" -Force
```

With this line of code, you're saying to **move all XML** files, and I think you should just be referencing the current file within your loop.  Here it is (rewritten a tiny bit for an easier to debug `ForEach` loop).

```
$dir = 'C:\temp\source'
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *xml 
ForEach($xmlFile in $xmlFiles){
    $Instrument = Select-Xml -Xpath '/deal' -Path $xmlFile.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If($Instrument.node.innertext -eq "FX_Cross"){
        Move-Item -Path $xmlFile.FullName -Destination "C:\temp\destination\FX" -Force
    }
    Else{
        Move-Item -Path $xmlFile.FullName -Destination "C:\temp\destination\" -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks extract below

iam required to check MM.DEPOSIT

<deal instrument="MM.DEPOSIT" name="MM.DEPOSIT.USD" role="TAKER">
<version>1</version>
<last_modified by="SPGAuctions3149LBN">20190204135352</last_modified>
<manual>N</manual>
<non_negotiated>N</non_negotiated>
<deal_date>20190204</deal_date>
<deal_time>13:53:43</deal_time>
<deal_datetime>20190204135352</deal_datetime>
<trade_date>20190204</trade_date>
<trade_time>13:49:42</trade_time>
</deal>